# Flex: SSL Certificate information gathering

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, ssl, certificate

I need to get some SSL information (such as the 'issued by' parameter and so on).
I know you can get the certificate status with a recent Adobe addition (secureSocket.serverCertificateStatus) but i need to know as much as possible about the certificate and hence my question.

Any info and tips will be highly appreciated,

with regards,

Mike

Comment: As far as I know this information is not exposed to Flash in any way.  Can you get at this information via the DOM?  IF so, then you may be able to use ExternalInterface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

By using secureSockets.serverCertificate property, one can gather various intel about the current certificate as specified here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SecureSocket.html#serverCertificate